# css issue with background image on mobile browser

Tags: css, image, mobile, background

the black background doesn't show properly on a mobile / tablet (ie on an iphone, nexus etc)
Although it works on laptop/computer browsers.

fiddle code : http://jsfiddle.net/Q6LND/

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="directory">        
 <div id="background">
      <div id="bgtop">
        <div id="nav">
          <ul class="navlist">
            <li class="first active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about-us/">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/how-it-works/">How it works</a></li>

            <li><a href="/pricing/">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
          </ul>


    <div class="loginDiv">
                    <a class="loginA" href="/login/" id="signinbutton"><span class="loginSpan">Sign In</span></a>
            <a class="loginA" href="/register/" id="registerbutton"><span class="loginSpan">Register</span></a> 
        </div>
        </div>



        <div class="clr"></div>
      </div><!--/bgtop-->
    </div><!--/background-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any help appreciated.

thankyou

Comment: your going to have to give quite a bit more than that if you want assistance... what have you tried? where is your code? a link to a fiddle is way better than a link to a site as the site may change rendering this question useless to future users.

Comment: right. i have added the code on fiddle.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it... all you have to do is:

**Add min-width in your body selector.**

```
body{min-width:1069px}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QJMQ6/1/

Actually, when width of the device is small, width of the body also become small as it's width is 100% of `<html />`. and things going out of this become visible because of `overflow:visible` as default property of body. do `body{overflow:hidden}`, things will get hidden but background will work properly. so better to set `min-width` of body there.

your fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6LND/1/

Comment: have you checked this on your mobile browser? it doesn't show the whole background on mobile. it has a cut down after showing 85% of BG